# "No target" error using Make

Tags: make

I'm learning how to use `make` and makefiles, so I wrote this little file:

```
%.markdown: %.html
    pandoc -o $< $@
```

But when I run `make`, all I get is `make: *** No targets.  Stop.` What's going on?

Comment: Are those spaces or a tab in front of the `pandoc` command. Make is notoriously picky about those being a tab and not spaces.

Comment: @slm: it's a tab. I read somewhere that Windows' EOL are not compatible, so I converted to whole file to Unix compatible EOL.

Comment: I guess u can use ```.SUFFIXES: .markdown .html```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Problem:

You problem is that `make` doesn't know about your targets.

You can run your above Makefile with `make stackoverflow.markdown` for example and it will work.

`make` only, however, will fail, since you only specified how to create your targets, but not which.

As [leiaz point's out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140934/72471) the above pattern rule is called an [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules).

### Makefile:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.html)
TAR = $(SRC:.html=.markdown)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TAR)

%.markdown: %.html
    pandoc -o $< $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TAR)
```

### Explanation:

`SRC` get's all source files (those ending in `.html`) via Makefile's [`wildcard`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908351/3739455).

TAR [substitutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12071918/3739455) each source file listed in `SRC` with a target ending with `.markdown` instead of `.html`.

[.PHONY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145605/3739455) lists non-physical targets that are always out-of-date and are therefore always executed - these are often `all` and `clean`.

The [target `all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2515000/3739455) has as dependency (files listed on the right side of the `:`) all `*.markdown` files. This means all these targets are executed.

```
%.markdown: %.html
    pandoc -o $< $@
```

This snippet says: Each target ending with `.markdown` is depended on a file with the same name, except that the dependency is ending with `.html`. The [wildcard `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406471/3739455) is to be seen as a `*` like in shell. The `%` on the right side, however, is compared to the match on the left side. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406471/3739455).

**Note** that the whitespace sequence infront of `pandoc` is a <kbd>TAB</kbd>, since `make` defines that as a standard.

Finally, the phony `clean` target depicts how to clean your system from the files you've created with this Makefile. In this case, it's deleting all targets (those files that were named `*.markdown`.

Comment: Great answer and these are other links I found when trying to further understanding it : [wildcard function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html), [substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs), and [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: One more question please : can `makefile` create files from scratch or it only updates existing files? Because when I delete the generated files, it stops to work. Silly question I know, but this is Newfoundland to me ^^"

Comment: you mean if there are no .markdown files, then they will be created? yeah it should do that as far as I know

Comment: Alright then. I'll do some more digging. Thanks for your answers, thanks to you I'm on the right way now : )

Comment: hehe no probs, have fun :)

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for the great answer. The way you have explained is very easy to understand the reason behind the command wasn't working and a very detailed instructions on how to proceed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

[Pattern rules are implicit rules.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules)

You have no targets defined in your Makefile. You can specify the target on the command line : `make something.markdown` will use the recipe to create `something.markdown` from `something.html`.

Or you can add to your Makefile a rule specifying default targets.

```
all: file1.markdown file2.markdown
```

Or [with a wildcard :](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards)

```
all: *.markdown
```

When you run just `make`, [the first target of the first rule is the default goal](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html#Goals). It doesn't need to be called `all`.

So above, the target `all` have all the files you want to make as prerequisites, so when you `make all`, it will make all the listed files.